# Could I replace one-word part of speech with whole-sentence representing same part of speech without sense replacement?

Tags: sentence-construction, parts-of-speech

> Noun - part of speech in grammar denoting a figurative or real thing or person.

Could I replace a one-word noun with multiple words representing the same part of speech? 
Example:

> Panther strikes.

The noun is 'panther' because panther is an animal.

> Big pink panther that like striking strikes.

'Big pink panther that like striking' is an animal. Could I say that it's a one part of speech? If so, could I say that it's the noun and make replacement with one-word 'panther'? Then, I could use as a subject any multiple-words noun, if so.

Comment: Yes, I mean panther.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing a noun with a more complex expression is using a "noun phrase". For example,
"That movie struck me as funny."

We can expand "movie" by turning it into a noun phrase:
"That Peter Sellers movie 'The Pink Panther' struck me as funny."

So, the answer to your question is "Yes, we do it all the time."

Comment: What similar English language mechanisms like noun phrases do we have in presence?

Comment: There are phrases for each of the five parts of speech: nouns, verbs, adjectives, adverbs, and prepositions. Check out the Wikipedia article "phrase".

Comment: Could I use all adjective grammar rules for the adjective phrase, for example?

Comment: I'm not sure that the usage rules about the order of different kinds of adjective would apply. What rules are you thinking about?